# Can't import plotnine

Tags: plotnine

Getting an error when trying to import plotline; I pip installed Unicode, but still seeing the same error. Not sure what else I need to install.

```
import plotline as p9


ImportError: cannot import name 'unicode'
```

Comment: Please provide full traceback of the exception, plotnine version and your Python version.

Comment: ... and check the filenames of the .py files in your working directory -- clashes there with python library files can lead to this error.